# Asynchronous code in custom ESLint rules

Tags: javascript, protractor, static-code-analysis, eslint

**The Story and Motivation:**

We have a rather huge end-to-end Protractor test codebase. Sometimes it happens that a test waits for a specific fix to be implemented - usually as a part of a TDD approach and to demonstrate how a problem is reproduced and what is the intended behavior. What we are currently doing is using Jasmine's `pending()` with a Jira issue number inside. Example:

```
pending("Missing functionality (AP-1234)", function () {
    // some testing is done here
});
```

Now, we'd like to know when we can rename the `pending()` back to `it()` and run the test. Or, in other words, when the issue `AP-1234` is resolved or sent to testing.

**The Current Approach:**

At the moment, I'm trying to solve it with a [custom `ESLint` rule](http://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-rules), [`jira` NodeJS module](https://github.com/steves/node-jira), and [`Q`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q). The custom `ESLint` rule searches for `pending()` calls with at least one argument. Extracts the ticket numbers in format of `AP-` followed by 4 digits and uses `jira.findIssue()` to check its status in Jira. If status is `Resolved` - report an error.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
"use strict";

var JiraApi = require("jira").JiraApi,
    Q = require('q');
var jira = new JiraApi("https",
    "jira.url.com",
    "443",
    "user",
    "password",
    "2");

module.exports = function (context) {
    var jiraTicketRegex = /AP\-\d+/g;

    return {
        CallExpression: function (node) {
            if (node.callee.name === "pending" && node.arguments.length > 0) {
                var match = node.arguments[0].value.match(jiraTicketRegex);

                if (match) {
                    match.forEach(function(ticket) {
                        console.log(ticket);  // I see the ticket numbers printed
                        getTicket(ticket).then(function (status) {
                            console.log(status);  // I don't see statuses printed
                            if (status === "Resolved") {
                                context.report(node, 'Ticket {{ticket}} is already resolved.', {
                                    ticket: ticket
                                })
                            }
                        });
                    });

                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Where `getTicket()` is defined as:

```
function getTicket(ticket) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    jira.findIssue(ticket, function(error, issue) {
        if (error) {
            deferred.reject(new Error(error));
        } else {
            deferred.resolve(issue.fields.status.name);
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

*The problem is:* currently, it successfully extracts the ticket numbers from the `pending()` calls, but doesn't print ticket statuses. No errors though.

**The Question:**

The general question is, I guess, would be: can I use asynchronous code blocks, wait for callbacks, resolve promises in custom `ESLint` rules? And, if not, what are my options?

A more specific question would be: what am I doing wrong and how can I use Node.js `jira` module with `ESLint`?

<sub>Would appreciate any insights or alternative approaches.</sub>

Comment: Does response from Jira come at all? Could you check it inside `getTicket` function? I personally would not use ESLint in this case, it is supposed to be used to check if your code is written correctly and if you follow style guides; from my point of view missing tests is not the part of code check, it's more like your team internal processes. Also, this kind of requests may slow your ESLint executions significantly, if anyone runs it in real-time in their editor, calls will be made very often and will slow down the entire check. I am not sure about async support in ESLint  though.

Comment: @MichaelRadionov if I put the exact same code outside of the rule - I see the responses coming from Jira - I can check the status for every requested ticket - this part works like a clockwork. Overall, I agree with you that eslint is probably not a good tool to use for this kind of task. It's probably more my curiosity driving it :) How would you automate this? Thank you!

Comment: Should these checks for missing tests fail your actual Protractor tests?

Comment: @MichaelRadionov yup, I think it's okay to fail a test in this case (I already like where you are going with this - make this a part of a test run?..)

Comment: Yeah, kinda. I suppose it also would be nice to keep `pending`, because it shows in the report that there are some unfinished parts.

Comment: btw, is Jasmine's `pending()` actually working for you in Protractor or do you have a custom function as a replacement?

Comment: @MichaelRadionov `pending()` works, but with some exceptions - for instance, if there is an `it()` after the `pending()` - the `it()` is just ignored and is not executed. Btw, we are using [`jasmine-spec-reporter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-spec-reporter).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The short answer is - no, you can't use asynchronous code inside of the rules. ESLint is synchronous and heavily relies on `EventEmitter` when it walks AST. It would be very hard to modify ESLint code to be async, but at the same time guarantee that events will be emitted in the right order.
I think your only choice might be to write a sync rule that outputs enough information into the error message, then use one of the parsable formatters like `JSON` or `UNIX` and then create another application that you can pipe ESLint output to and do a async lookup in Jira based on the error message.

Answer (score 3):

These answers remain valid in 2018.

For some insights from the eslint devs, see [this conversation](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/eslint/b2JEmoBrj2k) we had on their mailing list.

For a working example, in my ["pseudo eslint plugin"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-vuln-regex-detector) I opted to use expensive but synchronous APIs and warn users about how best to use the "plugin" in their CI process.

Answer (score 2):

*Note: it does not answer original question about support of async code in ESLint custom rules, but provides an alternative solution to the issue.*

I personally would not use *ESLint* in this case, it is supposed to be used to check if your code is written correctly and if you follow style guides; from my point of view missing tests is not the part of code check, it's more like your team internal processes. Also, this kind of requests may slow your *ESLint* executions significantly, if anyone runs it in real-time in their editor, calls will be made very often and will slow down the entire check. I would make this *JIRA* check a part of *Protractor* flow, so if the ticket is resolved, you will get a failed *Protractor* spec. *(copied from the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33881778/asynchronous-code-in-custom-eslint-rules#comment55542503_33881778) to make the answer complete)*

*Jasmine* allows to mark specs as pending using [`xit()`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html#section-Pending_Specs). I am not sure about `pending()` though, it works weird in *Protractor*. Also, *Jasmine* allows to call `pending()` inside a spec, so it will be marked as pending, but it is not implemented for *Protractor* yet ([see issue](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2454)). Knowing that, I would use a custom helper to define "pending specs", which should be checked for *JIRA* issue status. I guess you can still use *Q* to work with promises, I'll just post an alternative using *WebDriver* promises without external dependencies. Here is a modified version of `getTicket()`:

```
function getTicketStatus(ticket) {

    // Using WebDriver promises
    var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();

    jira.findIssue(ticket, function(error, issue) {
        if (error) {
            deferred.reject(new Error(error));
        } else {
            deferred.fulfill(issue.fields.status.name);
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Then there is a custom helper function:

```
function jira(name) {
    // Display as pending in reporter results, remove when pending() is supported
    xit(name);

    // Using Jasmine Async API because Jira request is not a part of Control Flow
    it(name, function (done) {

        getTicketStatus().then(function (status) {
            if (status === 'Resolved') {
                done.fail('Ticket "' + name + '" is already resolved.');
            } else {
                done();
                // pending() is not supported yet https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2454
                // pending();
            }
        }, function (error) {
            done.fail(error);
        });
    });

}
```

Usage example:

```
jira('Missing functionality (AP-1234)', function () {
    //
});

jira('Missing functionality (AP-1235)');
```

In case if request to *JIRA* fails or issue has a status *Resolved*, you will get a failed spec (using *Jasmine* [async API](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/introduction.html#section-53)). In all situations you will still have this spec duplicated as pending in reporter results. I hope it can be improved, when `pending()` functionality inside a spec is [implemented](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2454).